# Mapping strings to multiple types for json objects?

Tags: json, go

I want to create a map that I can transform into a json object such as

```
{
   "a": "apple",
   "b": 2
}
```

but golang specifies that the map be declare with types, so I can have map[string]string or map[string]int.  How do I create a json object like the above?

Note: I won't know what data and/or types I need until runtime or when I need to create the json object.  Therefore I can't just create an object like

```
type Foo struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can always use `interface{}`to store any type. As the documentation in the `encoding/json` package says:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal unmarshals the JSON into the concrete value contained in the interface value. If the interface value is nil, that is, has no concrete value stored in it, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> bool, for JSON booleans
>   float64, for JSON numbers
>   string, for JSON strings
>   []interface{}, for JSON arrays
>   map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
>   nil for JSON null

Just do the following:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{"a":"apple", "b":2}
```

Comment: Can one of your values also be an array?

`m := map[string]interface{}{"a":"apple", "b":2, "c": ["foo", 2, "bar", false, {"baz": "bat", "moreFoo": 7}]}`

Comment: @BrantleyBeaird Sure! The empty interface (`interface{}`) holds any type, including arrays. Since your array contains arbitrary types in itself, it would become type `[]interface{}`

Comment: Interface types (of which `interface{}` is one specifying no methods) can hold any underlying types, but as such they add runtime overhead in terms of memory use (additional type information is stored at the moment its value is converted to an interface value) and some processing.  Reasonable price to pay for some of the flexibility you may be used to from a dynamic language, but not something to use when there is no reason to do so.  Interface types can hold any underlying type except another interface type.  This includes plain types like int, float64, but also arrays, maps, channels etc.

Comment: How to make it right `m := map[string][]interface{}{"a":"apple", "b":2, "c": ["foo", 2, "bar", false, {"baz": "bat", "moreFoo": 7}]}` ?

Comment: @ErtuğrulAltınboğa I was a bit unclear. For composite literals (structs, arrays, slices, and maps) you must first specify the type. It would be: `m := map[string]interface{}{"a": "apple", "b": 2, "c": []interface{}{"foo", 2, "bar", false, map[string]interface{}{"baz": "bat", "moreFoo": 7}}}`

Answer (score 8):

To respond to the comments, I think it is easier to add type definitions for Map and Slice, then you don't have to worry about complex literal declarations:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Map map[string]interface{}
type Slice []interface{}

func main() {
   m := Map{
      "a": "apple",
      "b": 2,
      "c": Slice{"foo", 2, "bar", false, Map{"baz": "bat", "moreFoo": 7}},
   }
   fmt.Println(m)
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions