# map a string to a map with different values

Tags: json, go, struct

```
{'award_name':
{'note':'good job!','value':10,'number':1,'date-received':'DATE'}
}
```

I am creating a struct to store all this data, but I'm confused on what format it should be in. You are mapping a string to a map of different types, how do you create that? Do I need to make another `struct` to store the layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapping strings to multiple types for json objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18526046)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the structure in advance then just use

```
x := make(map[string]interface{})
x["foo"] = 1
x["bar"] = "A string"
```